# R Loop function

Tags: r, function, time-series

I'm trying to write a function in R to compute some indicators within a data frame.

Let's say my DF is:

```
df <- structure(list(Delt.1.arithmetic = c(0.002519607, 0.03247049, 
0.01268653, 0.01105899, -0.003642582, -0.02468412, -0.04560344, 
0.0501897, -0.01963724, -0.01068217, -0.1203641, 0.1604419, 0.001868874, 
0.04664339, 0.01482009, 0.05694765, 0.2006065, 0.0187676, 0.02741049, 
0.0339604)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

1. I'd like to make packets of five values, starting with the first value until the fifth value.
   Thus, we have something like `df[1:5,]`
2. Ok now, I'd like to know within this sample, what sign is each observation.
   `sign(rv_returns[1:5,])`

We got this output `[1]  1  1  1  1 -1`
1 is corresponding to a plus, -1 is corresponding to a minus.

3. Moving forward, I'd like to compute the probability of getting a (+), and a (-).
   I don' know how to automate this part, by looking we know for the previous output that P(1) = 4/5 and P(-1) = 1 - P(1). Omitting the 0 value of the function sign().
4. We know the probability of getting the sign of DF[1:5,], we look now for the strength of possible fluctuation. Basically, we compute the average of the most probable sign. As an example, considering the first series of five, gives us a probability of 4/5 to get a positive number. So we take all four positive numbers together and compute their mean. Manually we have something like
   `(DF[1) + DF[2] + DF[3] + DF[4]) / 4` which equals to x.
5. We now have the most probable sign of the data range, and its average strength.
   We'd like to compare this (x) value, to the 5 + 1 value of the dataset. The sixth value then.
   The sixth value is equal to -0.02468412, our little computations for step 1 to 4 are equal to 0.01101861.
   I'd like to compare their signs. If DF[6]'s sign = Computed Sign we have a boolean value like TRUE or CONFIRM. Otherwise we have a FALSE. Basically, we have + = + : TRUE// + = - : FALSE.
6. Finally, we want to repeat this function for the entire data set, taking a period of n previous values. In this case n = 5. So if my DF has 1000 Observations, the last looped arguments will consider DF[994:999,] and compare the computed value with the 1000th value (step 5).
7. The results of this function should be stored in a variable.
   An example of accomplished variable might be

```
  [6,]      TRUE
  [7,]      FALSE
  [8,]      TRUE
  [9,]      FALSE
  [10,]     TRUE
```

Additionnal info: our compared value has to be considered in the next data range. For example, in the second looped function we should study DF[2:6,] over observation DF[7]. The third one will consider DF[3:7,] over observation DF[8] and return and TRUE/FALSE.

Thank you for your help,

Wish you all the best.

```
predictor <- function() { 
  x <- 1
  y <- 5
  w <- x + 1
  z <- y + 1
  P1 <- rv_returns[x:y,]
  P2 <- rv_returns[w:z,]
  
  repeat {
    w <- w + 1
    z <- z + 1
    sign(rv_returns[w:z,])

}
}
predictor()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! I suggest you take a look at [ask], which gives tips on how to write a descriptive, non-ambiguous title.

Answer (score 0):

If your final desired output is simply boolean values, you could combine the intermediate steps you described. I am not sure why you need to calculate the mean (if ultimately you just need the sign of the mean), so I am adding in the commented code to go that route if needed:

```
# Define n
n <- 5

# Define second column to store Boolean values 
df[,2] <- NA

# Run `for` loop
for(xx in (n + 1):nrow(df)){
  # Find most common sign in previous five values
  sgn <- as.numeric(names(table(sign(df[(xx - n):(xx - 1),1]))[order(table(sign(df[(xx-n):(xx - 1),1])), decreasing = TRUE)][1]))
  
  # Determine if the sign of the current value equals the most common sign
  df[xx, 2] <- sgn == sign(df[xx,1])

  # or if need the means
  #mn <- mean(df[(xx-n):(xx - 1), 1][sign(df[(xx - n):(xx - 1),1]) == sgn])
  #df[xx,2] <- sign(mn) == sign(df[xx,1])
}
```

Output:

```
#    Delt.1.arithmetic    V2
# 1        0.002519607    NA
# 2        0.032470490    NA
# 3        0.012686530    NA
# 4        0.011058990    NA
# 5       -0.003642582    NA
# 6       -0.024684120 FALSE
# 7       -0.045603440 FALSE
# 8        0.050189700 FALSE
# 9       -0.019637240  TRUE
# 10      -0.010682170  TRUE
# 11      -0.120364100  TRUE
# 12       0.160441900 FALSE
# 13       0.001868874 FALSE
# 14       0.046643390 FALSE
# 15       0.014820090  TRUE
# 16       0.056947650  TRUE
# 17       0.200606500  TRUE
# 18       0.018767600  TRUE
# 19       0.027410490  TRUE
# 20       0.033960400  TRUE
```

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Delt.1.arithmetic = c(0.002519607, 0.03247049, 
0.01268653, 0.01105899, -0.003642582, -0.02468412, -0.04560344, 
0.0501897, -0.01963724, -0.01068217, -0.1203641, 0.1604419, 0.001868874, 
0.04664339, 0.01482009, 0.05694765, 0.2006065, 0.0187676, 0.02741049, 
0.0339604)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -20L))
```

#### EDIT

As requested, a more detailed breakdown explanation. In the above, everything is put together for more parsimonious code. Below is a step-by-step breakdown. I suggest running it line-by-line to see how it works. Also note this is a "brute-force" method and other may have more elegant means to achieve the same goal. Note that none of the intermediate steps are saved/indexed, so are intentionally overwritten on each iteration of the loop (in contrast to the last step, which saves the final value in `df` by indexing at `df[xx, 2]`)

Hope this helps and happy coding!

```
for(xx in (n+1):nrow(df)){
  
  # get signs for pervious n values
  signs_prevn <- sign(df[(xx-n):(xx - 1), 1])
  
  # create a table for these values
  tbl <- table(signs_prevn)
  
  # Order it where the most common (-1 or 1) is first
  tbl <- tbl[order(tbl, decreasing = TRUE)]
  
  # extract the first (most common) element from the table
  # this gives the frequency as an integer, with the name
  # being the sign (-1 or 1)
  tbl <- tbl[1]
  
  # Get the "name" of the most common sign (-1 or 1)
  # This is a character variable so convert to numeric
  sgn <- as.numeric(names(tbl))
  
  # See if the most common sign meets the sign of the current position
  df[xx, 2] <- sgn == sign(df[xx,1])
}
```

Comment: May you explain your code if you have a couple of minutes please ? In particular the sgn part. Thanks :)

Comment: @mkch - sure! see if the above edit provides some clarity. Good luck and glad it worked! If there are no better answers, consider accepting this (by clicking check mark) so that other users know this question is closed out (helps tidy up the site :)